# Create custom shipping method for creating order programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, create-order, custom-shipping-method

i've successfully created an order programatically, the problem is i can only use shipping method which already exist like 'flatrate_flatrate' and 'freeshipping_freeshipping' like this:

```
$this->_shippingMethod = 'flatrate_flatrate';
//or
$this->_shippingMethod = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';

$order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddressModel)
          ->setShippingMethod($this->_shippingMethod);
```

i want to add shipping with custom shipping price,title, and carrier method title for my order.